# Mounting a location with a name

Tags: windows-xp

Is theer a way to mount a local path with a user friend name (similar to a device name). For eg,  mount 'D:/Users/Rahul' folder as 'Rahul'.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make it a devicename, but you can use the subst command to make it a single letter drive name.

this command in command prompt will make a new drive letter U: pointing to your folder

```
subst U: d:\Users\Rahul
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use environment variables if this suits your needs

**Update:** See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable for examples on how to create environment variables

Comment: How about an example?